# Query details in a JSON with URL commands

Tags: json, url, esp8266, espeasy

I have a JSON file, see below. The URL to this JSON file is `http://host/json`. Is there a way to in the URL add options, that only displays the value of say Switch, Relay 2?

(this is a JSON file from ESPEasy of the ESP8266's)

```
{"System":{
"Build": 118,
"Unit": 2,
"Uptime": 68,
"Free RAM": 28488
},
"Sensors":[
{
"TaskName": "Switch",
"Relay1": 0.00
},
{
"TaskName": "Switch",
"Relay2": 0.00
},
{
"TaskName": "Switch",
"Relay3": 0.00
},
{
"TaskName": "Switch",
"Relay4": 0.00
},
{
"TaskName": "Switch",
"Relay5": 0.00
},
{
"TaskName": "Switch",
"Relay6": 0.00
},
{
"TaskName": "Water",
"CounterMunicipality": 0.00,
"Total": 0.00,
"Time": 0.00
},
{
"TaskName": "Water",
"CounterBorehole": 0.00,
"Total": 1.00,
"Time": 726077.00
},
{
"TaskName": "Air",
"Temperature": nan,
"Humidity": nan
},
{
"TaskName": "System",
"Uptime": 65.00
}
]}
```

Comment: Can you phrase the question a little more clearly?  You want to make a URL based on values in the JSON object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking to the source code [WebServer.ino](https://github.com/ESP8266nu/ESPEasy/blob/master/WebServer.ino), it should be possible to select a task using `tasknr` argument see :

```
boolean handle_json()
{
    String tasknr = WebServer.arg("tasknr");
....
    byte taskNr = tasknr.toInt();
    byte firstTaskIndex = 0;
    byte lastTaskIndex = TASKS_MAX - 1;
    if (taskNr != 0 )
    {
        firstTaskIndex = taskNr - 1;
        lastTaskIndex = taskNr - 1;
    }
...
}
```

Then you should get the Relay 2 using :

> http://host/json?tasknr=2

Comment: Then you may accept the answer, and eventually vote for it.

Comment: Thanks to make me know ESP Easy it seeems a nice project